# Exponential function using binomial approach and approximation by power series, both using python. Why different results?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, exponential-function, python

Why using power serie the result was so different ? I imagine it happened due to the truncation, I used 20 terms, are more terms needed ?

[image]

**EDITED: The code is below**

```
import numpy as np
import cmath 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def exponentialFunction(x, interval):
    y = [0 for i in range(interval)]
    for n in range(0,interval):
        y[n] =  (1 + x[n]/(n+1))**n
    return y

def truncatedExponentialFunction(x, interval):
    y = [0 for i in range(interval)]
    for n in range(0,interval):
        y[n] = 1 + x[n] + (x[n]**2)/np.math.factorial(2) + \
        (x[n]**3)/np.math.factorial(3) + \
        (x[n]**4)/np.math.factorial(4) + (x[n]**5)/np.math.factorial(5) + \
        (x[n]**6)/np.math.factorial(6) + (x[n]**7)/np.math.factorial(7) + \
        (x[n]**8)/np.math.factorial(8) + (x[n]**9)/np.math.factorial(9) + \
        (x[n]**10)/np.math.factorial(10) + (x[n]**11)/np.math.factorial(11) + \
        (x[n]**12)/np.math.factorial(12) + (x[n]**13)/np.math.factorial(13) + \
        (x[n]**14)/np.math.factorial(14) + (x[n]**15)/np.math.factorial(15) + \
        (x[n]**16)/np.math.factorial(16) + (x[n]**17)/np.math.factorial(17) + \
        (x[n]**18)/np.math.factorial(18) + (x[n]**19)/np.math.factorial(19) + \
        (x[n]**20)/np.math.factorial(20)
    return y

    
interval = 10000
k = np.linspace(0, 8*np.pi, interval)
z = complex(0,1)
x = z*k

y = truncatedExponentialFunction(x,interval)
w = exponentialFunction(x,interval)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)

ax[0, 0].set_title("Exp. Function - real")
ax[0, 0].plot(k, np.real(w))
ax[0, 1].set_title("Exp. Function - imag")
ax[0, 1].plot(k, np.imag(w))

ax[1, 0].set_title(" Power Serie - real")
ax[1, 0].plot(k, np.real(y))
ax[1, 1].set_title(" Power Serie - imag")
ax[1, 1].plot(k, np.imag(y))


fig.tight_layout(pad=1.0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, your exponential function is *not* the exponential function, $e^x$, but it computes something completely different. For example, when $n=1$ we have $y[1]=1+\frac{1}{2}x[1]$, not $e^{x[1]}$.

Comment: @Levent when n = 1 whe have y[1] = 1 + x[1] + (1\2)x[1]^2 + ...

Comment: I disagree that this is the case for exponentialFunction in your code.

Comment: @Levent, but, that is not the power series for exponential function ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Look at your code for the function called "exponentialFunction". What does it compute? It does not compute the exponential function. It sends the sequence $[x_0, x_1, x_2,...]$ to $[ 1, 1+\frac{1}{2}x_1, (1+\frac{1}{3}x_2)^2,... ]$.

Comment: It calculates the value of y for each value of x

Comment: If you posted this code as text instead of an  image one could at least verify to see if it does what you say. I am having doubts also. This is a borderline question because it has little to do with mathematics.

Comment: @KurtG. Good Idea, I did it right now

Comment: I compared a few `y` and `w` values with the built-in `np.exp(x[i])` . What is happening is that on the imaginary axis the exponential function is $sin$ and $cos$ which are known to have slowly converging power series. Your approach to truncate the series to $20$ terms is too crude to work for large imaginary values. Your function `exponentialFunction` does a much better job.

Comment: True! I ran the code for smaller intervals and they are not so different. The problem is with large numbers

Comment: @KurtG.  I don't think I can choose your comment as the chosen answer to the question because your answer is in a comment format. So, to leave the question answered, I'll put an answer based on our conversation. If you want to write an answer too, please just tell me that I delete mine. Thank you!

Comment: I don't want to write an answer. This is not math. Just practical coding. Please use my tips to get to the bottom of the problem.